# Checking if value exists in php array - not working?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have the following php code that gets a serialized array from a mysql database, then unserializes it. This is working fine. The following code:

```
$row=mysql_fetch_array($result);
$mydata=$row[0];
$unser=unserialize($mydata);

echo "$mydata<br>";
print_r($unser);
echo "<br>";
echo $unser[1901];
```

The output is this:

```
a:2:{i:2070;s:4:"0.00";i:1901;s:4:"1.00";}
Array ( [2070] => 0.00 [1901] => 1.00 ) 
1.00
```

So far, so good. Now, I'm trying to write the code so that it checks if the array key 1901 exists. For that, I tried this:

```
$search_array = $unser;
if (array_key_exists('1901', $search_array)) {
     echo "The key 1901 is in the array";
}
```

However that is returning an error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "an error", doesn't tell us much. Please quote the error!

Comment: Of course, sorry! The error is: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_VARIABLE

Comment: On which line does that error occur?

Comment: after or before `array_key_exists`?

Comment: @MarkBaker, just before he calls `array_key_exists`.

Comment: Does if(isset($search_array['1901'])) work and will it do what you need?

Comment: All your semicolons are in the right place? i.e. there is no semicolon missing on the line before the erroneous line?

Comment: the error is on the line where I then echo that the key is in the array.

Comment: If its not a missing semicolon, it could be an unbalanced speech mark.  Please edit your post to show the lines in between the portions that you showed us already.

Comment: This isn't related to the question, but it makes no sense that you serialize an array and store it in the database instead of just letting your database store each array input. That's what databases are for, after all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the following code:

```
$mydata= 'a:2:{i:2070;s:4:"0.00";i:1901;s:4:"1.00";}';
$unser=unserialize($mydata);

echo "$mydata<br>";
print_r($unser);
echo "<br>";
echo $unser['1901'];

$search_array = $unser;
if (array_key_exists('1901', $search_array)) {
     echo "<br />The key 1901 is in the array";
}
```

It will work correctly:

```
a:2:{i:2070;s:4:"0.00";i:1901;s:4:"1.00";}
Array ( [2070] => 0.00 [1901] => 1.00 )
1.00
The key 1901 is in the array
```

Check if you have more code after the lines of code you have posted. I think is another piece of code which is confusing you.

Answer (score -1):

```
echo $unser[1901];
```

should be

```
echo $unser['1901'];
```

Also you can do

```
if(isset($unser['1901'])) { }
```

instead of array_key_esists()

Comment: Correct, but not 100%. Some times, PHP recognize you are doing some mistakes and know `1901` is not a constant.

Comment: `$unser[1901]` is completely fine. And `array_key_exists()` and `isset()` are not the same in this case.

Comment: That didn't work unfortunately. Now the error is Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING

Comment: Post more source code. Error is probably happening 1 line before posted code.

Comment: It's strange that's all the code there is between the echo that works fine and the search_array I initially tried